# WebRTC Java Server?

Tags: java, websocket, webrtc

Is there a way to make a simple Java server be able to connect with a WebRTC browser page?

I'm asking because I have a Java server that talks to a Websocket browser page and it'd sure be nice to have it capable of making a second WebRTC connection for fast and unreliable data transfers.

I'm having a hard time finding WebRTC Java server code.

Edit: It appears the status of this question is applied to the ones who applied it. As they apparently have minimal knowledge of my question.

Comment: I'd love to know who the geniuses were who closed this question. It is certainly an important one, and the author did indeed show a more than minimal understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. There is a couple of examples in the webrtc source code base (https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/). Look under `talk/examples`.

However unreliable data channels are currently being deprecated and swapped for reliable ones. Google Chrome will probably drop unreliable (UDP based) data channels altogether in the near feature and support only reliable (SCTP based). More to the point unreliable data channels are currently bandwidth limited (about 30Kbits/s). I don't know what you are doing but I am pretty sure that websockets (TCP based) are fast enough and using WebRTC will just be a huge time investment for little to none benefit.

Comment: I saw some java code in there but close examination shows that it's simply wrapper code.

My issue with reliable data transfer is (1) Data stacking and (2) It doubles your ping time as it not only has to send data but get a confirmation.
My ping is at 20ms. Sending an unreliable packet gets me a 50fps rating on network speed. Having it do a confirmation packet has a round trip of 40ms, slowing it down to 25fps. Without movement prediction that produces a stuttery experience.

Furthermore if I'm sending packets at 60fps and it has a max speed of 25fps I have packets stacking on packets.